# Does creating a pivotTable in VBA have a limit on number of source rows?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I've managed to create a macro which creates pivotTables and pivotCharts from some sample source data (around 20 rows), this all works fine.

However, when I use a month's sample data - approximately 215,000 rows I suddenly get the error 'type mismatch' in the lines where the pivotTable is created.

```
t1wkb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, 
SourceData:=currentsht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, _
Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="[" & t1wkb.Name & "]"
& wsNew.Name & "!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTableName", _
DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

The strange thing is I can create a pivotTable manually from the large dataset, recording that process and playing just that back within excel gives me the error.

Does anybody know whether this is a problem with my code or if I've hit a hard limit of some sort of the VBA constructor for excel pivotTables?

Thanks for any light shed on this issue,
David

Comment: It's possible that when you play back your recorded macro you're trying to create a table with the same name as the one you created when you recorded the code.  If you haven't previously deleted that, it may cause an error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim, I don't think that's the issue though.  I have a single sheet for my data, I start recording when I create a new sheet and pivotTable on that new sheet.  I then deleted the sheet and ran the recorded macro.  It created the sheet but failed when creating the pivotTable

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this issue as well and my workaround is use `string` instead of `range` when provide SourceData Value in creating pivot cache. I was able to do pivot table around 70K rows this way.

My VBA code as follow.

```
Dim pvt_source_worksheet As Worksheet
Dim pvt_destination_worksheet As Worksheet

Dim last_cell_range As Range
Dim source_range_string As String

Set pvt_source_worksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(yourworksheet)
Set pvt_destination_worksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(destination worksheet)

Set last_cell_range = pvt_source_worksheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
source_range_string = pvt_source_worksheet.Name & "!R1C1:R" & last_cell_range.Row & "C" & last_cell_range.Column

'Create pivot cache

Set pvt_cache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
                SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                SourceData:=source_range_string)

'Create pivot table

Set pvt_tbl = pvt_cache.CreatePivotTable( _
                TableDestination:=pvt_destination_worksheet.Range("A1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The limitation concerns the number of rows when a Range object is passed. The maximum number is 64K.
Using a string I passed more than 100K rows to the pivot.

Comment: This answer appears to be a duplicate of the original answer.